# Want to set a floating button in UItableview for scrolling up and down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll, floating

I want to add a floating button on the UItableview. The location of the button should stay set at one position.

The purpose of the button should be to scroll up and down through the uitableview.

Please suggest me if there is any direct framework available which can be implemented in the project to achieve this.

Comment: UIKit would be the framework you would use. Why would you want to add a button to scroll a table view? Why wouldn't the user just scroll the table like all other table views?

Comment: I have a long list of data, in case i am in middle of somewhere and want to jump directly to top or bottom; for that purpose i need it.

Comment: Set up the table's index down the right side. That's what it's for.

Comment: I don't feel that's gonna sort out my issue.